# Get data from secondary table in Prisma2

Tags: graphql, nexus, prisma, nexus-prisma

I have a `User` table that contains user data. I also have a `Relationship` table that contains a `parent_id` and a `child_id` as well as the incrementing `id`. Each Parent can have many Children and I am trying to retrieve the array of children using the `parent_id`. I am currently getting an array, but the array only contains the `Relationship` table data.

How do I get the data from the `User` table? I was under the impression that because there is a relationship the following should work, but it doesnt.

```
query {
  getChildren {
    user{
      id
      name
      email      
    }
  }
}
```

The relevant code is as follows:
Query:

```
export const getChildren = queryField('getChildren', {
  type: 'User',
  list: true,
  resolve: async (_parent, {}, ctx) => {
    const userId = getUserId(ctx);
    if (!userId) {
      // TODO -think I might need to throw an error here
      return;
    }
    const children = await ctx.prisma.relationship.findMany({
      where: {
        parent_id: userId,
      },
    });
    return children;
  },
});
```

schema.prisma:

```
model Relationship {
  child_id            Int
  id                  Int  @default(autoincrement()) @id
  parent_id           Int
  child               User @relation("Relationship_child_idToUser", fields: [child_id], references: [id])
  parent              User @relation("Relationship_parent_idToUser", fields: [parent_id], references: [id])
}

model User {
  created_at          DateTime       @default(now())
  email               String?        @unique
  id                  Int            @default(autoincrement()) @id
  ischild             Boolean        @default(false)
  name                String?
  password            String
  children            Relationship[] @relation("Relationship_child_idToUser")
  parents             Relationship[] @relation("Relationship_parent_idToUser")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The query below should do it

```js
  prisma.relationship.findMany({
    where: {
      parent_id: user_id,
    },
    include: {
      child: true,
    },
  })
```

You need to specify the `include` param explicitly to include the relationship in the output.

Comment: Im still getting the same result when I add the include. No problems from the linter though, so we are on the right track

Comment: I'm getting the data mate. This is the query used: `const data = await prisma.relationship.findMany({
    where: {
      parent_id: 1,
    },
    include: {
      child: true,
    },
  })`
And this is the response:
`[ { child_id: 2,
    id: 1,
    parent_id: 1,
    child:
     { created_at: 2020-05-26T15:33:13.171Z,
       email: null,
       id: 2,
       ischild: true,
       name: 'child',
       password: 'child' } } ]`
Have you added the relations correctly?

Comment: This is the query Im using `query {
  getChildren {
  id
    name
  }
}` is that similar to yours?

Comment: Ive checked the DB and the tables are all linked correctly

Comment: I have just checked and the prisma 'findMany` query is returning the correct values, but the values are not showing in the Playground. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: The query should be `query {
  getChildren {
    child {
      name
    }
  }
}` and the nexus query should be `export const getChildren = queryField('getChildren', {
  list: true,
  type: 'Relationship',
  resolve: (_root, _args, ctx) => {
    return ctx.prisma.relationship.findMany({
      where: {
        parent_id: 1,
      },
      include: {
        child: true,
      },
    })
  },
})`